# How to use FLANN installed from synaptic

Tags: c++, flann

I tried to compile FLANN with cmake, but the only result was a giant headache.

So I found [here](http://varuagdiary.blogspot.hk/2012/03/installing-flann-on-ubuntu-1110.html) this solution through PCL repository and synaptic. The installation seems gone well, but now I don't know how to use the installed package.

Quoting FLANN's [documentations](http://www.cs.ubc.ca/~mariusm/uploads/FLANN/flann_manual-1.6.pdf) :

> An example of the compile command that must be used will look
>   something like this: `g++ flann_example.cpp -I $FLANN_ROOT/include -o flann_example_cpp` where `$FLANN ROOT`
>   is the library main directory.

But it's not clear to me where `$FLANN_ROOT` is.

Comment: Did you compile FLANN from sources or use launchpad repo?

Comment: I followed the instruction in the link for the second method using synaptic, so I think the launchpad repo

Answer (score 1):

The `$FLANN_ROOT` is a path where the library was installed. This is mostly relevant when you build and install manually (especially when installing to non-standard locations).

When installed by the packaging system (Synaptic - I guess Ubuntu?) the library headers will be most likely installed in `'/usr/include'` or `'/usr/local/include'`. Normally you do not have to use the `-I` then as those paths are examined by default.